# mongoose model, array of strings, array of objects structure

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to design my database model and i dont have clue how to fit `array` of `strings` and `array` of `objects` into it. My current model is:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const schema = new Schema({
    email: { type: String, unique: true, required: true },
    hash: { type: String, required: true },
    createdDate: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    settings: {
        favorites: { /* ??? */ },
        cart: { /* ??? */ },
        states: {
            favorites: { type: Boolean, default: true },
            search: { type: Boolean, default: false },
            category: { type: Schema.Types.Mixed, default: false }
        }
    }
});

schema.set("toJSON", { virtuals: true });

module.exports = mongoose.model("User", schema);
```

`favorites` data structure is `['234', '564', '213', '782']`

`cart` example data structure is:

```
[
    { quantity: 5, marketId: '234' },
    { quantity: 2, marketId: '564' },
    { quantity: 7, marketId: '213' },
    { quantity: 3, marketId: '782' }
]
```

How can i add this as configuration to the `mongoose` model?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Favorites must be an array of String like this: `favorites: [String]`

For the cart array we have two main options:

1. We can define the cart as an array of `subdocuments`.

```js
const schema = new Schema({
  email: { type: String, unique: true, required: true },
  hash: { type: String, required: true },
  createdDate: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
  settings: {
    favorites: [String],
    cart: [
      {
        quantity: Number,
        marketId: String
      }
    ],
    states: {
      favorites: { type: Boolean, default: true },
      search: { type: Boolean, default: false },
      category: { type: Schema.Types.Mixed, default: false }
    }
  }
});
```

2. Or we can declare cart as an array of `schema types`.

```js
const schema = new Schema({
  email: { type: String, unique: true, required: true },
  hash: { type: String, required: true },
  createdDate: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
  settings: {
    favorites: [String],
    cart: [
      new Schema({
        quantity: Number,
        marketId: String
      })
    ],
    states: {
      favorites: { type: Boolean, default: true },
      search: { type: Boolean, default: false },
      category: { type: Schema.Types.Mixed, default: false }
    }
  }
});
```

For both of them, when you create a document, it will look like this, note that mongoose added _id field in the card items.

```
{
    "settings": {
        "states": {
            "favorites": true,
            "search": false,
            "category": false
        },
        "favorites": [
            "234",
            "564",
            "213",
            "782"
        ],
        "cart": [
            {
                "_id": "5e6cd0bd53feb32d50699b79",
                "quantity": 5,
                "marketId": "234"
            },
            {
                "_id": "5e6cd0bd53feb32d50699b78",
                "quantity": 2,
                "marketId": "564"
            },
            {
                "_id": "5e6cd0bd53feb32d50699b77",
                "quantity": 7,
                "marketId": "213"
            },
            {
                "_id": "5e6cd0bd53feb32d50699b76",
                "quantity": 3,
                "marketId": "782"
            }
        ]
    },
    "_id": "5e6cd0bd53feb32d50699b75",
    "email": "abc@def.net",
    "hash": "hash...",
    "createdDate": "2020-03-14T12:40:29.969Z",
    "__v": 0,
    "id": "5e6cd0bd53feb32d50699b75"
}
```

If you don't want `_id` fields in cart array, you can add `_id: false` option the cart schema like this:

```js
    cart: [
      new Schema(
        {
          quantity: Number,
          marketId: String
        },
        { _id: false }
      )
    ],
```

Here are some useful docs:

[Arrays](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html#arrays)

[Subdocuments](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html)