# How to structure nested object model properly in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to define the following mongoose model for a case. Strange I can not see a proper documentation about what I'm trying to do. In the end I want to have only 1 collection "Case"
which documents are nested object like this:

```
const CaseSchema = new Schema({
  clientDataType: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    enum: [
      'dataSchema1',
      'dataSchema2',
    ],
  },
  clientData: {
    type: "Either dataSchema1 or dataSchema2",
    required: true,
  },
  caseDataType: {
     type: String,
     required: true,
     enum: ['type1', 'type2', ...]
  },
  caseData: {
    type: "One of 6 types of cases again they are schemas",
    required: true,
  }
}, { timestamps: true });
```

And here is mockup for dataSchema1 same goes for dataSchema2

```
const dataSchema1 = new Schema({
    field1: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  fiedl2: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  field3: {
    type: "One of subschemas of my choice",
    required: true,
  },
  ...
}, { timestamps: true });
```

Is mongoose capable of doing that or I must skip mongoose for this kind of case model. Basically at  the end I wan't to submit this object and let mongoose validate it for me.

Comment: You can only use string values for enum

Comment: I know that im asking how to actually implement what i need

Comment: Just like this: `clientData: {
      type: dataSchema1,
      required: true
    },`

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60682796/11717458) answer for an example how to nest sub documents.